How to set a custom tag only inside a single scope in sentry?
I have multiple exceptions being captured in a single python job.
I would like to set different tags for each of these exceptions, but the tag from the previous ones keep carrying over to the latter ones.
I have tried the following, but failed.
sentry_sdk.set_tag("a", 1)

try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    with sentry_sdk.configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.set_tag("b", 2)
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)


sentry_sdk.set_tag("c", 3)

try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    with sentry_sdk.configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.set_tag("d", 4)
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e) 
        # desired behavior: tags a,c,d are recorded
        # actual behavior: tags a,b,c,d are recorded

Arn't scopes the correct way to achieve this?
